# Adding Credit Card in to Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I am Trying to Add Credit Card On heroku then there message is showing "Unable to verify your Card Please Try later or contact your financial intitution for help"

Answer (score 1):

This is because your bank is declining the payment.

1. Check that you're entering all the correct details
2. Take a look into your bank last movements to see if there is any declined payment
3. Try with other credit/debit card or other payment option

Answer (score 1):

If its an Indian credit Card :

Heroku mentioned

India issued credit card verifications
Effective October 1, 2021, new Reserve Bank of India (RBI) regulations state that no automatic recurring payments may be processed using India-issued credit cards without an additional factor of authentication (AFA).

Because of these new regulations, Heroku is currently unable to verify and process payments with India-issued credit cards for Heroku Online customers. Enterprise India-based customers are not impacted.

source: https://help.heroku.com/04UOS4A3/why-am-i-seeing-the-error-unable-to-verify-your-card-when-trying-to-add-or-update-a-credit-card

Comment: Is there any alternative ?, Or then how does Enterprise customers are doing payment ?

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Are there any alternatives?